# GCalendar API - Exclude Events By ID?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm particularly trying to write this in C#, but has anyone managed to create a LIST request for events that OMIT events by a list of IDs? The idea here is to omit Google Calendar events that I've already pulled before in my previous requests (this would be stored in my application data) so that the events are always new. Here's my current list request code below:

```
// Create Google Calendar API service.
            var service = new v3GCal.CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });


            var today = DateTime.Today;
            var tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);
            // Define parameters of request.
            v3GCal.EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("manager@affirmmedicalweightloss.com");
            request.TimeMin = today;
            request.TimeMax = tomorrow;
            request.ShowDeleted = false;
            request.SingleEvents = true;
            request.Q = "";
            request.MaxResults = 10;
            request.OrderBy = v3GCal.EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;
```

I'm not too hopeful - I've been digging around trying to find something with this feature, but with no luck. I would ideally include in the request something like:

```
"id NOT IN " + collection of existing id strings
```

But I don't see documentation on this anywhere.

Has anyone pulled this off, or considered filing a feature request for it? I thought of filing one, but given the issue tracker that I found at issuetracker.google.com, I'm not too hopeful this would get implemented anytime soon...

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is regarding recurring event, you can try to use [`Events: instances`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/instances) that returns instances of the specified recurring event. Doing so excludes the recurring events, but includes all expanded instances. If not, you can file a bug [here](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/).

Comment: I'm not sure that's quite what I'm looking for though. I already leave out recurring events - but currently, I keep pulling the same ten events since they are the ones that immediately qualify in my specified window. So I'm hoping to compare the event's I've already brought into my portal's DB with the new ones I'm pulling, if that makes sense